# how to include dates where no value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query like so -

```
select CAST(jobrun_proddt as Date) as 'Date', COUNT(*) as 'Error Occurred Jobs' from jobrun
where jobrun_orgstatus = 66 and jobmst_type <> 1
group by jobrun_proddt
order by jobrun_proddt desc
```

Not every date will have a count.  What I want to be able to do is the dates that are blank to have a count of 0 so the chart would look like this -

```
2014-11-18  1
2014-11-17  0
2014-11-16  0
2014-11-15  0
2014-11-14  0
2014-11-13  1
2014-11-12  0
2014-11-11  1
```

Currently it's not returning the lines where there's no count.

```
2014-11-18  1
2014-11-13  1
2014-11-11  1
```

edit to add that the jobrun table DOES have all the dates, just some dates don't have the value I'm searching for.

Comment: It will only show the count for dates which are available in the table.

Comment: The easiest and most efficient way is a `Numbers`-table to create sequences of dates(using `DATEADD`). Then you can join with this table. http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Comment: One of the most common database query questions, and one of the hardest to search for. Basic concept: Generate the complete list of dates you are interested in, then outer join them with the dates for which there is data.

Comment: So the table `jobrun` doesn't have those dates? Then I think you have no option but to create a temporal table with the date range you need, and select from that table and then `LEFT JOIN jobrun`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use `Recursive CTE` to generate the Dates.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2014-11-18') AS dates --Max date
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(dd, -1, dates)
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  dates > '2014-11-11') -- Min date
SELECT a.dates,
       Isnull([Error_Occurred_Jobs], 0)
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Cast(jobrun_proddt AS DATE) AS Dates,
                         Count(*)                    AS [Error_Occurred_Jobs]
                  FROM   jobrun
                  WHERE  jobrun_orgstatus = 66
                         AND jobmst_type <> 1
                  GROUP  BY jobrun_proddt) B
              ON a.dates = b.dates 
         Order by a.dates desc
```

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @whoisearth Yes it should be removed. And keep it in the last line.

Comment: that did it!  I think I understand now I have a few similar queries to do so I'll try to break it down for those.

Answer (score 2):

If you have data for all dates, but the other dates are being filtered by the `where` clause, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select CAST(jobrun_proddt as Date) as [Date],
       SUM(CASE WHEN jobrun_orgstatus = 66 and jobmst_type <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as [Error Occurred Jobs]
from jobrun
group by jobrun_proddt
order by jobrun_proddt desc
```

Comment: This is actually much more elegant and it was what I was trying to figure out!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to join to a table or list of generated sequential dates using OUTER JOIN so that for the dates with no matches to your jobrun_orgstatus you can use ISNULL or COALESCE to return 0.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you must specify a particular date range
then you should connect your table with "left join"

```
DECLARE @start DATE, @end DATE;
SELECT @start = '20141114', @end = '20141217';

;WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end) + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.all_objects
)

SELECT 'Bob', DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start) as 'xdate' FROM n;


select CAST(jobrun_proddt as Date) as 'Date', COUNT(*) as 'Error Occurred Jobs' from jobrun
left join n on DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start) = jobrun.jobrun_proddt
where jobrun_orgstatus = 66 and jobmst_type <> 1
group by jobrun_proddt
order by jobrun_proddt desc
```